# add_rewrite_rule is redirecting instead of rewriting url

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I have a page that is accessible at `/products/`.

I want to be able to access it at `/products/canada/ontario/toronto/` (and not redirect to `/products`)

The place names after `/products/` should be query variables that correspond to country, region, city.

I have tried the following code:

```
function km_tags() {
    add_rewrite_tag('%city%', '([^&]+)');
    add_rewrite_tag('%region%', '([^&]+)');
    add_rewrite_tag('%country%', '([^&]+)');
}
add_action('init', 'km_tags');

function km_rewrite_rules() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^products/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?','index.php?page_id=25&country=$matches[1]&region=$matches[2]&city=$matches[3]','top');
}
add_action('init', 'km_rewrite_rules');
```

I have also tried the following, instead of `add_rewrite_tag`:

```
function km_vars($vars){
    $vars[] = 'city';
    $vars[] = 'region';
    $vars[] = 'country';
    return $vars;
}
add_filter('query_vars', 'km_vars');
```

The problem is that when I visit `/products/canada/ontario/toronto/` I am redirected to `/products`

How can I get WP to preserve the entered url but serve content from the `/products` page?